# Problem in DataBinding an Enum using dictionary approach to a combobox in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding

I have a Dictionary which is binded to a combobox. I have used dictionary to provide spaces in enum.

```
public enum Option {Enter_Value, Select_Value};

Dictionary<Option,string> Options;

    <ComboBox                                        
        x:Name="optionComboBox"
        SelectionChanged="optionComboBox_SelectionChanged"
        SelectedValuePath="Key"
        DisplayMemberPath="Value"
        SelectedItem="{Binding Path = SelectedOption}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path = Options}" />
```

This works fine.

My queries:

**1.** I am not able to set the initial value to a combo box.
In above XAML snippet the line

```
SelectedItem="{Binding Path = SelectedOption}"
```

is not working. I have declared SelectOption in my viewmodel. This is of type string and I have intialized this string value in my view model as below:

```
SelectedOption = Options[Options.Enter_Value].ToString();
```

**2.** The combobox is binded to datadictionary which have two options first is "Enter_value" and second is "Select_value" which is actually Option enum.

Based on the Option enum value I want to perform different action.

For example

if option is equal to option.Enter_value then

Combo box becomes editable and user can enter the numeric value in it.

if option is equal to option.Select_value value then

the value comes from the database and the combo box becomes read only and shows the fetched value from the database.

Please Help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try binding SelectedValue, not SelectedItem if SelectedOption is of type Option.

About your second question: Based on selection you can hide your ComboBox and display a TextBlock or TextBox in it's place. Or you can use RadioButtons and enable or disable input accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply majocha.. for the second solution , actually I am using the listview and combo box is displayed in one of the column. I have defined as a GridView. Cell Template. Therefore I can't use radio button or show/Hide the control.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem, probably, is that you've bound `SelectedItem` to a property of the wrong type.

An `ItemsControl` iterates over its `ItemsSource`'s enumerator to build its list of items.  The enumerator for your dictionary is of type `KeyValuePair<Option, string>`.  So your `SelectedOption` property must also be of that type - if you look in the Output window when your application is running, you'll probably see a data-binding error to that effect there.

I can't understand your second question.

**Edit**

Okay, it's a lot easier to just provide a working example than to explain why code that I can't see isn't working.

First, you need a view model class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and that exposes `SelectedItem`, `Value`, and `IsValueReadOnly` properties, and that correctly raises `PropertyChanged` events for those properties when the selected item changes.

```
public enum Option
{
    EditOption,
    OtherOption
} ;

public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Dictionary<Option, string> _Items;
    private KeyValuePair<Option, string> _SelectedItem;
    private string _Value;

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        _Items = new Dictionary<Option, string>
        {
            {Option.EditOption, "Editable value"},
            {Option.OtherOption, "Other value"}
        };
    }

    public Dictionary<Option, string> Items
    {
        get { return _Items; }
    }

    public KeyValuePair<Option, string> SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _SelectedItem; }
        set
        {
            _SelectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
            OnPropertyChanged("IsValueReadOnly");
            OnPropertyChanged("Value");
        }
    }

    public bool IsValueReadOnly
    {
        get { return _SelectedItem.Key != Option.EditOption; }
    }

    public string Value
    {
        get { return IsValueReadOnly ? "Read-only" : _Value; }
        set { _Value = value; }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler h = PropertyChanged;
        if (h != null)
        {
            h(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Now the XAML for your `ComboBox` and `TextBox` looks like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication6.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        xmlns:WpfApplication6="clr-namespace:WpfApplication6" 
        Title="MainWindow">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <WpfApplication6:MyViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel>
      <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
                DisplayMemberPath="Key"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"/>
      <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}"
               IsReadOnly="{Binding IsValueReadOnly}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks Robert for the reply. I will try the first solution, also I have re-framed the second question, please see if you can give me the solution

Comment: I have tried the first solution but it doesn't work. Still I get selected index -1